# Set working directory when Seed data

Tags: entity-framework-migrations, entity-framework-4.3

I'm trying to insert some sample data (Seed data) using EF 4.3 Migration.

The problem is I want to read data from xml file. But when I run `Update-Database` cmdlet, I got error like  `Could not find a part of the path 'C:\SampleData\'`.

Is there anyway to set the working directory to current project folder when I run `Update-Database` from my powershell console.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Did you try to use PowerShell commands (`get-location` / `set-location "..."`) or direct access to .NET API `[System.IO.Directory]::GetCurrentDirectory()` / `[System.IO.Directory]::SetCurrentDirectory("...")`?

Comment: I have tried .NET API [System.IO.Directory]::GetCurrentDirectory() but it is not working too. And I don't want set current directory with hard-coded location. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered your question there http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/437709c0-6933-4ccb-8995-02438500b68b

:)